# Code change in Spock spec is not recognised in Idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, spock, gmavenplus

I have a simple PoC of a Spock integration with maven.

The problem I face is that when I modify code in Spock spec and run it in idea then change is not picked up and the old code is executed. I need to call `mvn verify` in order to reflect the change.

When I modify the production code though - change is reflected and test don't pass in Idea.

My sample project:

https://github.com/kkocel/spockarticle

Is there a way to enable code change detection in Idea or am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [gmavenplus-intellij-plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7442-gmavenplus-intellij-plugin) or manually add the groovy directory as test-source-root. Furthermore, the gmaven plus in your pom is outdated.